# Unable to view recently inserted results in H2

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm using the H2 Database system for a small java project I'm working on. If I manually run the Queries, everything works as expected, but when I run my program, I get the following:

```
Constructed: INSERT INTO library VALUES (null,'TEMPORARY_EFFECT_1369614387100','asdf',0,0,0,0,0)
Constructed: SELECT id FROM library WHERE name='TEMPORARY_EFFECT_1369614387100'
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-171]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:135)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkOnValidRow(JdbcResultSet.java:2956)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:2962)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:306)
```

I'm not exactly sure what is going on. According to the JavaDocs for JDBC and H2, I'm doing things right (I think). The `INSERT` is executed by calling `db.createStatement().executeUpdate(...)` and the `SELECT via db.prepareStatement(..., ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception is typically caused by not calling [Resultset#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) prior to invoking one of the `ResultSet's` getter methods, appears to be `getInt` in this case.

Make sure to call

```
rs.next();
```

prior to using any of the getter methods.

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't exactly this but that helped solved my problem! I wasn't re-winding the result set after I counted the rows with a utility function. Thanks again!